# Broken external stylesheets

Tags: css

I am working on making a fake website for one of my courses in college. After trying to link my external stylesheet, I still cannot find out how to properly integrate it with my html doc. The link seems correct and even is listed in inspect element in chrome, however none of the styles are showing up.

I have tried looking up everything, from my school books to youtube videos and I've had no luck. I don't know if nav tabs or my one div has anything to do with anything not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> About Us! </title>
<link rel="fusionStyles" type="text/css" href="fusionStyles.css">
</head>
<h1> Food Fusion </h1>
<img src="photos/logo.jpeg.jpeg" alt="logo" />
<nav> 
<ul class="header">
<li> <a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
<li> <a href="breakfast.html">Breakfast</a> </li>
<li> <a href="extras.html">Appetizers and Extras</a> </li>
<li> <a href="lunch.html">Lunch</a> </li>
<li> <a href="dinner.html">Dinner</a> </li>
<li> <a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a> </li>
<li> <a href="locations.html">Locations</a> </li>
<li> <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a> </li>
<li> <a href="events.html">Events</a> </li>
<li> <a href="order.html">Online Ordering</a> </li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
<h1> About Us! </h1>
<body> 
<p> Default text. <p>
<img src="photos/generic.jpeg.jpeg" alt="interior" />

<p> More Default text. </p>
</body>
<footer>
<div class="navbar">
<a href="survey.html">Click here to take a quick survey about our 
performance! </a>
<a href="employment.html"> Want to join our staff? Click here!</a>
<p> &copy; </p>
</div>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't have content after your `</body>` or before the `<body>`. You also have a closing `</header>` with no opening `<header>` tag. Validate your HTML with https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: Here is the code for my css page, named fusionStyles.css, https://pastebin.com/gDfK0sp3

Answer (score 0):

The rel attribute on your  tag specifies the relation between your HTML file and you CSS file. In order to specify your "fusionStyles.css" as a stylesheet you have to specify it like so:
`<link rel="stylesheet type="text/css" href="fusionStyles.css" />`

Answer (score 0):

- Atribute *rel* in `<link />` is "stylesheet";
- You should rename file: EX: "logo.jpeg.jpeg" => "logo.jpeg"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it for you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <title> About Us! </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fusionStyles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <h1> Food Fusion </h1>
        <img src="photos/logo.jpeg.jpeg" alt="logo" />
        <nav>
            <ul class="header">
                <li> <a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="breakfast.html">Breakfast</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="extras.html">Appetizers and Extras</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="lunch.html">Lunch</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="dinner.html">Dinner</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="locations.html">Locations</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="events.html">Events</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="order.html">Online Ordering</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <h1> About Us! </h1>
    <p> Default text. <p>
    <img src="photos/generic.jpeg.jpeg" alt="interior" />

    <p> More Default text. </p>

    <footer>
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="survey.html">Click here to take a quick survey about our
            performance! </a>
            <a href="employment.html"> Want to join our staff? Click here!</a>
            <p> &copy; </p>
        </div>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for reformating it! However even though looking through the links again the css sheet styles still do not show up. Here is the pastebin link to my css styles. https://pastebin.com/gDfK0sp3

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure fusionStyles.css is in the same directory as the html file?